# Changing from Qt4 to Qt5: QtGui/QAction: No such file or directory in generated ui_ file

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake, build-error

I have to make sure my project builds both in Qt 4 (I have 4.7 installed) and Qt 5 (I have 5.5).

For that, in many places I have, in pro file:

```
NOT_QT_4 {
     QT += widgets
} else {
    #Nothing specific
}
```

and in code:

```
#ifdef NOT_QT_4
    #include <QtWidgets>
#else
    #include <QtGui>
#endif
```

Yet every time I switch build from Qt 4 to Qt 5, I get an error:

```
ui_somefile.h:14: error: QtGui/QAction: No such file or directory
 #include <QtGui/QAction>
                         ^
```

This is in a `ui_` file generated from a form created using the Qt Designer... so I can't put the defines that I use in normal code.

It is extremely difficult to get it to build: `Build->Clean All`, erase every single file on disk (`debug`, `release`, `make*`, `ui_*`), `Build->Clean All` again (useless of course), run `qmake`, build again ...
still I have to do it repeatedly because the `ui_` file seems to regenerate with defective info.

Since I have to make sue every commit builds in both Qt4 and Qt5 versions, I have to do this a lot right now...

How can I make it build correctly in Qt5 - and alternatively how can I clean that particular portion of the build easily ? (a clean build takes several minutes... giant project...)

Comment: ***Use out of source builds!***

Comment: @peppe What does that mean ?

Comment: Suppose you have your software in `mysoftware`, `mkdir qt4build; cd qt4build; /path/to/qt4/qmake ../mysoftware/ ; make` , that's your Qt 4 build. Rinse and repeat for Qt 5: `cd ..; mkdir qt5build; cd qt5build; /path/to/qt5/qmake ../mysoftware/ ; make`. Stop tampering the ***same*** build directory with artifacts from different build configurations. Just build ***out of source***.

Comment: In Creator the same is done in th Projects tab. Assuming both Qt versions are correctly configured in Tools->Options, go in the Projects pane. On the top configure two kits (one for Qt 4 and one for Qt 5), specifying a different, out of source build dir for each. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you put those ui_*.h files in a different location, such that the results could be different and compile uniquely between QT versions.

```
NOT_QT_4 {
   UI_HEADERS_DIR = foo
} else {
   UI_HEADERS_DIR = bar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do shadow build to get all your output files out from sources. And it seems uic.exe changed between Qt4 and Qt5. For my part I got Qt5.6 then I should write in my .pro greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets if not no ui_*.h are released. For cleaning properly your project I guess you should change some part of your makefile. What cleaner do use for ?